# DevExpress TreeListControl create custom cell template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I am having trouble binding stuff with [THIS CONTROL.](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfGridTreeListControltopic)

I want to create a custom cell template not the default one. When using the default cell template my binding works. Here is my project:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
        xmlns:dxt="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" >
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <dxt:TreeListControl Name="treeList">
            <dxt:TreeListControl.Columns>

                <!-- Custom Column -->
                <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="Name" Header="Name">
                    <dxt:TreeListColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="Blue" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxt:TreeListColumn.CellTemplate>                    
                </dxt:TreeListColumn>

                <!-- default Column -->
                <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="Position" Header="Position"/>

            </dxt:TreeListControl.Columns>
            <dxt:TreeListControl.View>
                <dxt:TreeListView Name="treeListView1" AutoWidth="True"
                                  KeyFieldName="ID" ParentFieldName="ParentID"/>
            </dxt:TreeListControl.View>
        </dxt:TreeListControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {        
        public MainWindow ( )
        {
            InitializeComponent( );
            treeList.ItemsSource = GetStuff( );
            treeListView1.ExpandAllNodes( );
        }

        public static List<Employee> GetStuff ( )
        {
            List<Employee> stuff = new List<Employee>( );

            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 1 , ParentID = 0 , Name = "Gregory S. Price" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 2 , ParentID = 0 , Name = "Irma R. Marshall" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 3 , ParentID = 0 , Name = "John C. Powell" } );

            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 6 , ParentID = 2 , Position = "Brian C. Cowling" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 7 , ParentID = 2 , Position = "Thomas C. Dawson" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 8 , ParentID = 2 , Position = "Angel M. Wilson" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 9 , ParentID = 2 , Position = "Bryan R. Henderson" } );

            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 10 , ParentID = 3 , Position = "Harold S. Brandes" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 11 , ParentID = 3 , Position = "Michael S. Blevins" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 12 , ParentID = 3 , Position = "Jan K. Sisk" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 13 , ParentID = 3 , Position = "Sidney L. Holder" } );

            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 14 , ParentID = 1 , Position = "Brian C. Cowling" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 15 , ParentID = 1 , Position = "Thomas C. Dawson" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 16 , ParentID = 1 , Position = "Angel M. Wilson" } );
            stuff.Add( new Employee( ) { ID = 17 , ParentID = 1 , Position = "Bryan R. Henderson" } );


            return stuff;
        }        
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

why is it that my (`<!-- Custom Column -->`) does not display the Name of the employe? what do I have to do to bind it to that Property? If I remove the CellTemplate it works but I want to have my custom style...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I'm going to answer before Devex Team :)

Change this :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="Blue" />
```

To this :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Data.Name}" Foreground="Blue" />
```

Or simply :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.Name}" Foreground="Blue" />
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want Path=Row.Name

Comment: @Aron Nope. I've already tested my answer before posting. 100% positive.

Comment: Works great you def answer it much faster than Devex Team! Here is the questoin at devExpress: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q473066

Comment: @TonoNam I can't blame them, they are handling 100s of questions everyday. plus they are probably off work by now.

Comment: To my mind, it's possible to use FieldName of TreeListColumn, instead of using overriding CellTemplates per each column

Comment: @AbZy thanks for the help. I posted a simple question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775007/pass-parameter-via-context-menu-to-devexpress-treelistcontrol  that is similar to this question. I will appreciate if you could help me on that one :)

Comment: @TonoNam This is one challenging question :) I will try to see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks :) If you cant no worries I appreciate a lot the help for this one!